# Single specific item within knockoutJS foreach binding loop

Tags: knockout.js

The following KnockoutJS `foreach` in select:

```
<select "foreach: ControllersAndActions">
   <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: $data.ControllerName}, foreach: Actions">
       <option data-bind="text: $data"></option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

renders the options tree styled the following way:

```
<optgroup label="NFC EAST">
     <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
<optgroup>
<optgroup label="NFC NORTH">
     <option>Chicago Bears</option>
</optgroup>
```

I need to do just that, except to also insert an initial empty option before the groups start, like this:

```
<option value=""></option>
<optgroup label="NFC EAST">
     <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
<optgroup>
```

How can I inject a singe item that is not "re-rendered" each time a foreach loop iterates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put the `foreach` binding on the `select` element instead of add the "foreach one level deeper" (e.g with using the [containerless control flow syntax](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)) and manually add the empty element:

```
<select>
   <option value=""></option>
   <!-- ko foreach: ControllersAndActions -->
   <optgroup data-bind="attr: {label: ControllerName}, foreach: Actions">
       <option data-bind="text: $data"></option>
   </optgroup>
   <!-- /ko -->
</select> ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

You can see it in action in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKkAn/1/).

Comment: I am applying a [Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) via a custom knockout binding and at the moment .chosen() is being rendered containerless flow foreach hasn't iterated yet, therefore casting only an empty option element to be a part of a selectable items list.

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov maybe there is a problem with your custom ko binding, because normally it should work. But I think you should post this new problem as a different question with your custom binding code included.